# Feedback on promises nodeJS storing username and passwords in text file

Tags: node.js

This is what I have to do: "This function should save their username and password into a text file called "database.txt" if the user does not already exist in that text file. If they already exist, you should generate an error letting them know that a user with that name already exists."

My current code:

```
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(DATA_BASE_FILE_PATH, "utf-8", (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        if (err.code === "ENOENT") {
          return fs.writeFile(
            DATA_BASE_FILE_PATH,
            `username:${username} - password:${password}${os.EOL}`,
            "utf-8",
            (err) => {
              if (err) {
                return reject(err);
              }
              return resolve("Saved username and password.");
            }
          );
        }
        return reject(err);
      } else if (data.includes(`username:${username} -`)) {
        return reject(`"${username}" username already exists.`);
      }
      fs.appendFile(
        DATA_BASE_FILE_PATH,
        `username:${username} - password:${password}${os.EOL}`,
        "utf-8",
        (err) => {
          if (err) {
            return reject(err);
          }
          return resolve("Saved username and password.");
        }
      );
    });
  });
};

register("henry", "qwerty123")
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Looking for feedback/what to improve. Im supposed to create a promise within the register function

Comment: Use `util.promisify` or `fs.promise` instead of creating them on your own.

Comment: "You may not use util.promisify or the built-in fs.promises. " Teacher made it a challenge for us not to use those for this lab actually

Comment: not related to promises but you can store the username password as a csv which would help in parsing the file. Using includes isn't the best idea

Comment: @TD With that arbitrary restriction it's very hard to improve. I would still recommend implementing it in that fashion, with 3 separate promises chained together, just that you'll have to implement the promisification on your own in 3 helper functions.